Are all normal random vectors affine transformations of standard normal random vector of same dimensionality?
Wikipedia gives this as a definition for a normal random vector: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector

A real random vector $X = (X_1, ..., X_k)^\top$ is called a normal random vector if [and only if] there exists a random $\ell$-vector $Z$, which is a standard normal random vector, a $k$-vector $\mu$, and a $k \times \ell$ matrix $A$, such that $X = AZ + \mu$.

I am wondering: is this still correct if we restrict $\ell = k$? If not, what's a counterexample?

You can't have a counterexample: it's not a theorem, it's a definition. What makes you think it doesn't work for $k=l$?

@lisyarus: I presume OP is wondering why $Z$ isn't simply a standard normal $k$-vector.

Your text question link is about a "multivariate normal distribution", which make the answer "yes, by definition".

@lisyarus it states there is some random l-vector Z; I thought it's possible that some normal random vector X exists such that no k-vector Z satisfies the statement but some l-vector Z does where l is not k

@BrianTung Yes, if this statement is true even when restricting l=k, why not have that as the definition?

Perhaps Wikipedia's definition just needs some re-writing as follows:
A real random vector $X = (X_1, ..., X_k)^\top$ is called a normal random vector if [and only if] there exists a standard normal random $\ell$-vector $Z$, a $k$-vector $\mu$, and a $k \times \ell$ matrix $A$, such that $X = AZ + \mu$.
